# C# Driver Factory for parallel testing using a Page Factory Model

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have taken my original Selenium Framework (using Page Object Model) and rebuilt it using the Page Factory functionality, having got a subset of tests working I now want to be able to run my tests in parallel I have built a simple Browser Switch class for running my tests sequentially but have hit a dead end in changing it for parallel running. I am very new to programming in general so any help greatly appreciated.

I have read Richard Bradshaw's Friendly tester article but his parallel browser factory does not work for my framework.

The Problem with the below is that I cant get it to run my tests in Parallel, I understand why (the static Instance means that it can only be in use once at a time) but all efforts to try and fix this have failed.

My Browser Class

```
 public class Browsers
    {
        private static IWebDriver webDriver;
        //public static ReportsManager reports;
        private static string baseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
        private static string browser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["browser"];
        public static void Init()
        {
            switch (browser.ToLower())
            {
                case "chrome":
                    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                case "ie":
                    webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    break;
                case "firefox":
                    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
            }
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(2192, -963);
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Goto(baseURL);
        }
         public static IWebDriver getDriver
        {
            get { return webDriver; }
        }
        public static void Goto(string url)
        {
            webDriver.Url = url;
        }
        public static void Close()
        {
            webDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Login Page

```
public class LoginPage
    {


        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "login-email")]
        [CacheLookup]
        private IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "login-password")]
        [CacheLookup]
        private IWebElement Password { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "loginBtn")]
        [CacheLookup]
        private IWebElement LoginButton { get; set; }


        public void EnterUserNameandPasword(string testName)
        {
            var testData = ExcelDataAccess.GetTestData(testName);
            UserName.EnterText(testData.Username, "UserName");
            Password.EnterText(testData.Password, "Password");
            LoginButton.Submit();
        }
    }
}
```

page class (this is where Richards Code fails in my framework and I cant find any way to make it work).

```
public class Page
    {
        private  static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
        {
            var page = new T();
            PageFactory.InitElements(Browsers.getDriver, page);
            return page;
        }

         public static LoginPage loginPage
        {
            get { return GetPage<LoginPage>(); }
        }
```

Login Test

```
[TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    [Category("login")]
    public class Login_Test : AutomationSetup
    {


        [Test]

        public void LoginTest()
        {
            Page.headerView.ClickOnLogin();
            Page.loginPage.EnterUserNameandPasword(_testName);
            Page.accountPage.ConfirmAtAccountPage(_testName);           
        }
```

and my generic Setup Class

```
{
        public string _testName


        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
         _testName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName;
        Browsers.Init();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            Browsers.Close();
        }
```

That should hopefully be enough of a sample of my framework to understand how it all works currently. I tried simply making my Browser non static but my Browsers.Init and Browsers.Close both stopped working.

When I try to run 2 or more tests simultaneously I get the following error on all but the 1st test to be started

```
Message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: have updated the question, the set up shown above wont let me run my tests in Parallel. When I try all my tests fail, I know why this is, I need to open up different instances of webDriver and the statics in the Browser class wont allow this. But I cant work out the changes I need to make to allow me to have different instances of webDriver open at the same time.

Comment: @RichardC Are you using VS Test? NUnit?

Comment: Nunit have added parralise to the tests and they are trying to run in parallel but failing with the error message I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite broad question, that includes nUnit (or other test framework), Selenium and Selenium Grid concepts. I would recommend working through this tutorial to get a hold of the basic concepts regarding parallel execution:

http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/parallel-testing-in-a-selenium-grid-with-vsts